# Are those two condition sentences equivalent?

Tags: c++, programming-languages

I'm learning Principles of Programming Language. My teacher gave me a question like following, which confused me a lot:

1:

```
if (Condition){
    Case A;
} else {
    Case B;
}
```

2:

```
Case B;
if (Condition) {
    Undo Case B;
    Case A;
}
```

Assume in c++, are these two programs equivalent?

---

Here is new added: Which one is better in performance and in what conditions?

Comment: What is your criteria for **equivalence**? Output, Time, Machine Cycles, Statements executed, or something else?

Comment: Does `Case B` have detectable side effects?

Comment: i think this is about logical equivalence

Comment: Thanks u all! Yep, it's logical equivalence. And as for what Rohit said, I didn't have the criteria, while you have opened my thought indeed. I would considered those aspects in my homework: P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of both the programs would be same. 
But in

```
if (Condition){
    Case A;
} else {
    Case B;
}
```

Only one statement in executed. Which leads to faster execution time in case 'Condition' is true.

In

```
Case B;
if (Condition) {
    Undo Case B;
    Case A;
}
```

`Case B` is always executed regardless of truth value of `Condition`. And when `Condition` is true, Total of 3 statements are executed.

> 1. Case B
> 2. Undo Case B
> 3. Case A

When `Condition` is false, both programs have more or less of the same execution time.

Comment: Hmmm, I doubt that this is a very good answer.  Consider the situation where Case B causes the multiplication of two large prime numbers.  Now undo that operation ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I thought of it as more or like a pseudo code. And moreover the *undo* operation was specified by OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not C++ but more like pseudocode

These two are equivalent

In 1. if condition is true then Case A is executed

In 2. if condition is true then we revert Case B and execute Case A